# Process Builder formula only partially evaluates(Edited version after trying with one of the proposed solutions)

Tags: formula, process, business-logic, builder

I am working on writing a formula inside process builder "Formula Evaluates to true" and it seems my logic is not working.

Suppose I have a following logic:

```
1 OR 2 OR 3 OR(4 AND 5)
```

Below is my formula which is I am writing which is not working:

```
OR(
   OR(
     1,
     2,
     3),
   AND(
     ISNEW(),
    (this is 4)
     5)
)
```

Ideally combination of 4 AND 5 should comes with OR along 1,2,3. So I deally if an user puts value for fields 1 OR 2 OR 3 OR (4 and 5) process builder should run but right now process builder is only running when either 1,2,3 is filled and 5 is satisfying.

**My real requirements:**

> Either Is_Medicare__pc OR Is_TriCare__pc OR Is_Medicaid__pc OR
>   Person_s_Age__pc >= 65 is filled on account then process builder
>   should update one field.

But right now process builder is running when either of `Is_Medicare__pc OR Is_TriCare__pc OR Is_Medicaid__pc is filled AND Person_s_Age__pc >= 65`.

Below is my formula which I build:

```
OR(
OR
(
[Account].Is_Medicare__pc,
[Account].Is_TriCare__pc,
[Account].Is_Medicaid__pc
),
AND
(
ISNEW(),
NOT(ISBLANK([Account].Person_s_Age__pc )),
[Account].Person_s_Age__pc >= 65
)
)
```

Note: `Person_s_Age__pc` is a formula field on contacts which is not supported by ISCHANGED() so i am using `ISNEW()` and `ISBLANK()`

EDIT : I am editing question based upon my recent work which I have done after giving a try to what @o-lexi has suggested.
1. Created one Date Formula field "65th BirthDate"(API NAME- X65th_BirthDate__c)
Formula for this field is as below:

```
IF(
```

AND( 
MONTH( Date_of_Birth__pc ) = 2, 
DAY( Date_of_Birth__pc ) = 29, 
NOT( 
OR( 
MOD( YEAR( Date_of_Birth__pc ) + 65, 400 ) = 0, 
AND( 
MOD( YEAR( Date_of_Birth__pc ) + 65, 4 ) = 0, 
MOD( YEAR( Date_of_Birth__pc )+ 65, 100 ) != 0 
) 
) 
) 
), 
DATE( YEAR( Date_of_Birth__pc ) + 65, 3, 1), 
DATE( YEAR( Date_of_Birth__pc ) + 65, MONTH( Date_of_Birth__pc ), DAY( Date_of_Birth__pc ) ) 
)
2. Created one Formula field as "Over 65"
3. Created one time-dependent PB which sets "Over 65" to TRUE after 0 hrs from 65th BirthDate
[image]

[image]

[image]

4. Modify my existing PB logic as
   OR( 1, 2, 3, Over_65__c )

Still not able to get what I was trying to achieve. If I put Date of birth on account as 15th May 1953 then upon saving 65th Birthday field is populating as 15th May 2018 but checkbox "Over 65"is not getting checked.Since checkbox is not getting checked my logic for updation of field value for "Insurance" to "Education Only" is also not set which I wrote in my another PB.Kindly help me on this issue.I am struggling alot on same from past 2 weeks and realaly running out of all ideas and knowledge. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Many thanks

Comment: My eyes kind of glaze over trying to grasp all the conditions - if I were you, I'd try and section out each part of the formula into smaller formulas. Easier to check each logic step, easier to write the more complex formulas, easier to debug, etc. Only downside is you have a good handful of fields. I've tried this before with very complex formulas and its helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that `Person_s_Age__pc` returns blank? Also, from my experience in certain scenarios when Process  Builder was kicking in, `ISNEW()` wasn't returning `true` for newly created record, and this could be when Workflow Rules ran already and updated the record, or PB gets evaluated multiple times.

If you want the formula to be triggered only by a change in age, use Birth Date field:

```
OR(
   OR(
     1,
     2,
     3),
   AND(
     OR(
        ISNEW(),
        ISCHANGED(Birth Date)),
     5)
)
```

EDIT:
I'm not sure what I was thinking by suggesting to use Birth Day change (!sic) as a trigger. So, as @DavidReed suggested in his answer, and I corroborated in my comment to his answer, you need to create the following:

1. date formula field (lets call it `65th BirthDate`)
2. flag field (e.g. `Over 65`)
3. time-dependent PB or WR to set a `Over 65` to true after 0 Hours from `65th BirthDate`'s date
4. Modify you PB formula to look like:

   OR(
   1,
   2,
   3,
   Over_65__c
   )

The `65th BirthDate` formula should be as found in [Sample Date Formulas](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=formula_examples_dates.htm&type=5) in *Adding Days, Months, and Years to a Date* section:

```
IF(
  AND(
    MONTH( Person_s_Birth_Date__pc ) = 2,
    DAY( Person_s_Birth_Date__pc ) = 29,
    NOT( 
      OR( 
        MOD( YEAR( Person_s_Birth_Date__pc ) + 65, 400 ) = 0, 
        AND( 
          MOD( YEAR( Person_s_Birth_Date__pc ) + 65, 4 ) = 0,
          MOD( YEAR( Person_s_Birth_Date__pc )+ 65, 100 ) != 0
        )
      )
    ) 
  ),
  Person_s_Birth_Date__pc( YEAR( Person_s_Birth_Date__pc ) + 65, 3, 1),
  Person_s_Birth_Date__pc( YEAR( Person_s_Birth_Date__pc ) + 65, MONTH( Person_s_Birth_Date__pc ), DAY( Person_s_Birth_Date__pc ) )
)
```

Comment: @o-lexi-Kindly note Birth Date can't be changed bcz a person must have only 1birth date. the problem here I am facing is we are using person accounts All of the fields are taken from contacts object. Since its a person account I am able to fetch contact's fields on account,everythng seems working fine.The real problem arises when a person's age changes from 64 to 65 then the process builder is not updating a field say "A" because person's age is a formual field on contact nd which is not stored in DB nd PB is not able to recognizing the same and  fields which shouldbe updated is not updating.

Comment: Formula field changes don't fire Process Builder, triggers, etc. That's not specific to Person Accounts.

Comment: @DavidReed Where exactly in my PB formula do I reference a formula field?

Comment: Sorry, @o-lexi - I meant to direct that comment to Harjeet, not to you. You don't reference a formula field, but that seems to be what he wants to do.

Comment: o-lexi as mentioned in your proposed solutions I have done following but still not able to complete my requirements.

Comment: 1) Please show me what formula you have for `X65th_BirthDate__c` field - it should be the formula I provided, and value it returns should be a date when person 65th birth date is e.g. 5/15/2018 for Birth date on 5/13/1953
2) your PB criteria should be something like 'record is new or date birth changed'

Comment: 3) after modifying the field formula and PB criteria you have to modify all your records the way that it will trigger PB criteria, e.g. - set all birth dates to null and set them back to the right values. this will create time-dependent events for each record to be executed in a future, or will set a flag for those already over 65 years old

Comment: @o-lexi You have mentioned in ur comments PB criteria should be something like record is new or Date of birth changed. Now my question is  date of birth can't be changed for a person then why this condition and also why only record is new. There may be 1000of records exists in account which has fate of birth field and were created many years ago. Pls correct me if I am wrong here or confuse on same

Comment: You need a universal criteria - it should apply to all records - imo, DOB is/should be set when a new record is being created, there are might be a case when DOB was entered incorrectly and could be updated - this will trigger PB rule evaluation. See my 3rd point - PB or WR criteria is not retroactive - it doesn't trigger re-evaluation on all records, but it will re-validate all existing time-dependent future actions. Luckily, with the offered design you don't have modify all records (as I describe as a 3rd point in my comment from above) - do this for all persons that are not over 65 yet.

Comment: ...this will create a time-dependent action record to set `Over_65__c` flag to true on their 65th birth day. For those, who are over 65 as of now you could set a flag to true

Comment: @o-lexi many many thanks for continuous reply om my questions but I still not able to solve this issue. Gill now I  created one date formula filed 65th birthday with formula exactly copy paste what you have provided. Second I created one checkbox field called Over 65.Third I created new process builder with criteria formula evaluates to true  65th Birthday equals the formula which you have PROVIDED AND actions as tome dependent one which will execute O hrs after 6th birthday with actions as set checkbox field Over 65 to trie. Fourth in my existing PB I put conditions like OR(1,2,3,OVER_65__c)

Comment: o-lexi I still not able to resolve the issue. I tested on one account where date of birth was 18th May 1953 so current age was 64 so ideally next day when someone opens the record the person's age will become 65 on 18th May 2018 which triggers a field update on one field called 'Market Insurancebility' with value 'Education Only'. But when I opened the record next day even though person' age becomes 65 but neither checkbox field got checked nor Market Insurancibikity field has Education Only value. I am really mad now with this issue from past 20days. Kindly help

Comment: @HarjeetSingh Process builder criteria should be `ISNEW() || ISCHANGED(Person_s_Birth_Date__pc )`

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, it sounds like your issue

> But right now process builder is running when either of Is_Medicare__pc OR Is_TriCare__pc OR Is_Medicaid__pc is filled AND Person_s_Age__pc >= 65.

may stem from a misunderstanding of how Process Builder criteria that include formula fields work.

You suggested that `Person_s_Age__pc` is a formula field based on, presumably, the Birth Date field. Formula fields are calculated each time they're accessed - there's no database event when the calculated value changes. As a result, what your formula:

```
OR(
   OR(
      [Account].Is_Medicare__pc,
      [Account].Is_TriCare__pc,
      [Account].Is_Medicaid__pc
   ),
   AND(
      ISNEW(),
      NOT(ISBLANK([Account].Person_s_Age__pc)),
      [Account].Person_s_Age__pc >= 65
   )
)
```

ultimately does is fire when any of the fields `Is_Medicare__pc`, `Is_TriCare__pc`, or `Is_Medicaid__pc` is changed to `true`, or when a new Person Account is created whose `Person_s_Age__pc` field *at the time of creation* is equal to or greater than 65.

If you have a Person Account where any of the fields `Is_Medicare__pc`, `Is_TriCare__pc`, or `Is_Medicaid__pc` is true and that person's birthday passes, making their age hit 65, nothing will happen because that's not a database event.

If you're changing records in the user interface to test this process, the behavior might look like the logic is behaving differently than you expect.

If you want to take action when a person's age ticks over to 65 without a change in the Birth Date field, you would need to either use time-dependent actions in Process Builder or Workflow Rules, or write a Scheduled Apex class to monitor these records.

I personally would probably go the Scheduled Apex route here because I tend to use code-based solutions, but @o-lexi has a clever declarative solution to allow you to do this with an extra formula field via scheduled action in Process Builder.

Comment: Many thanks @David Reed-Yes you correct my problem is when person's age becomes 65 then a field say 'A' is not setting to a expected value becuase person age is formula field nd updation of this field is not DB event nd my PB not able to recognize the same. Can you please help me hw to achieve this usng time dependent actions in PB as you suggested in your comments. time dependent actions I can see only Hours or Days nd I want PB to run when either Medicare,Tricare, Medicaid OR person's age becomes 65 if date of birth is provided. Many thanks nd I am sure you will definitely help me on same

Comment: I agree with David here - you need to create another date formula field (lets call it `65th Birthdate`), and use it in a time-dependent PB or WR to set a flag field (e.g. `Over 65`) after 0 Hours from `65th Birthdate`. Please see the formula in my edited answer - it appeared too long for the comment.