# Workflow rule not working as expected(not on update of a criteria)

Tags: workflow, force.com, field-update

I wrote one WF rule which seems to be not working

My requirement is whenever "Person's age" becomes 65 or more then it should update one field called 'Insurance Marketability'to a value called'Education Only'.

"Person's age" is a formula field on contact object which derives its value from another date field called "Date of Birth"."Insurance Marketability" is a picklist field.I am using Person's account concept so I have built logic inside Process Builder and WF created on Account.

Since there are few limitations of formula fields usage with PB and WF because any updates on Formula fields is not considered as DB events hence my field "Insurance Marketability" was not set to "Education Only". So I wrote one WF rule with Rule Criteria as "TODAY() - Date_of_Birth__pc >= 65" and Evaluation Criteria as   "Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and every time it's edited" and created one Field Update action on same as Update Insurance Marketability to Education Only.Also I checked "Re-evaluate Workflow Rules after Field Change" field to true

[image]
[image]

But it seems WF is only working. Its only working when I am clicking on EDIT button and then SAVE button on Account. Ideally my intention is suppose an account's date of birth mentioned as 7th May 1953 then on 7th May 2018 Insurance Marketability should be set as "Education Only" by only just refreshing that particular records or opening up that particular record(not with clicking on edit button and then simply click on save button).

When I changed my evaluation criteria to subsequently met criteria then WF rules is not triggering anything.

I have done researches on formula fields limitations in WF rule and PB so I went for creation a logic on Date of Birth field instead of Person' Age field but still I have no luck and stuck at same place only.

Also I read in some forums when I was doing researches that only thing which can save me here is a Scheduler but problem is I am novice in Customization and no idea about Scheduler

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

Kindly help

Comment: For context, see [previous question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/216595/process-builder-formula-only-partially-evaluates). Harjeet, one of the most important facets of that discussion was the use of *time-based* actions in your Process Builder - see o-lexi's answer.

Comment: Yup I agreed @David. I tried that too. Using time dependent actions in PB but those conditions only use for Days  and Hours wheras in my case it may be so many years like 65 years. How can we track all of these. I think I have done all of the things which were suggested by experts here but still left with same. Kindly help

Comment: The proposed solution was to set a time-based action 0 hours after a "65th Birthday" formula field. It was a good idea and sounded workable. Did you try it? If it did not work, why not?

Comment: @DavidReed I dont prefer Time Based workflow action because of The limit for time-based workflow action execution is 500 per hour, including any other time-based workflow action that may be in your system. Its sad if you have Millions of customer in your system :(

Comment: @PranayJaiswal You don't prefer Time-based workflow but suggesting it in your answer. Also, for millions of customers tuning 65yo is just once in a lifetime  event (if not any).

Comment: @HarjeetSingh What exactly issue did you run into with [my solution](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/216618/12440) ?

Comment: o-lexi I was giving a try to your proposed solution and I am facing below issue. 1. I created one Date formula field "65th BirthDate". 2. Created one checkbox field as Over 65. 3. I am not able to follow steps 3 as mentioned in your proposed solution "https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/216595/process-builder-formula-only-partially-evaluates/216662#216662". May I request you to guide me how to create a WF rule for your step no3 as you mentioned in your solution.Many thanks

Comment: o-lexi I am trying to create a WF rule for same with created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria and in rule criteria I am setting value for 65th BirthDate equlas 65 but on saving I am getting error as "Error: Invalid date (Valid date format 5/14/2018)". I am not sure How ro proceed with step no 3 as mentioned by you in your proposed solution https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/216595/process-builder-formula-only-partially-evaluates/216662#216662. Kindly guide me.I am still strugling to complete this requiremnt and I am stuck from past couple of weeks.Many thanks

Comment: I have edited my previous question "https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/216595/process-builder-formula-only-partially-evaluatesedited-version-after-trying-wit" after giving a try with solution which @o-lexi has provided. Still not able to achieve what I was looking for. Now my new field "65th Birthday "is updated as Date of birth+65 which I guess i correct. But the checkbox field "Over 65" is not getting set to TRUE if 65th Birthday value is 65 years plus date of birth mentioned on account

Comment: Lets say if a person has date of birth say 14th MAY 1953 then on 14th MAY 2018 field on account "Insurance Marketability" should be set as "Education Only". But after implementing what o-lexi has suggested it seems that if date of birth is 14th may 1953 then 65th Birthday field is populating as 14th May 1953 but checkbox field "Over65" is not getting checked. Also in my existing PB I have addded actions when Over65 is checked then set value for "Insurance Marketability" to "Education Only". I have posted edited version on my previous questions with all the screenshots of my work.Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

You are using a formula field. Formula field is not stored in database and are evaluated at run time.

1. As workflow rule fire only when there is change in data create/edit. As change in formula field is not excatly change in data as its not a field in database, thus the workflow wont fire automatically when Applicant reaches a certain age.
2. When you edit that record, then workflow rule fires and evalutes the criteria. During evaluation it finds that formula value has changed and should trigger a field update.
3. subsequently met criteria only fires when old value is different than new value. So before DML the formula value and after dmL formula value is same, it wont trigger the field update.

You have to use Scheduler/Time Based workflow for this behavior.

Below link mentions both approches to send email via Scheduler and via time based workflow.
http://www.simplysfdc.com/2015/02/salesforce-send-birthday-email.html

Comment: Many thanks for your comments. As I already mentioned in my question that I have done so much research and now aware that I have to go by custom way. I am novice in customization and will take a very much time to get a hand on the same for me. I alreday read somewhere that only thing which can help me on this is Scheduler but I have no idea on Scheduler. May I request you to kindly help me on same. Many thanks

Comment: updated links for the solution.

Comment: Many thanks @pranay jaiswal for your prompt response. But in my case I don't need any email to be sent. My requirement is to update Insurance Marketability field to Education only if Person's age becomes 65.Person's age is a formula field derives formula from another field Date of Birth which is date data type. So if Date of birth field is 9May 1953 then person's age becomes 65 due to the formula written behind the field. Now once person' age becomes equals or greater than 65 my Insurance Marketability field should be updated as Education only without clicking on Edit button on account detail

Comment: I have tried almost everything be it process builder or workflow rules or creating another field which copy  value of my formula field and refer new field in PB or WF buy nothing works for me. YOU suggested about scheduler which I read somewhere also don't know who yo achieve the same. The link which you shared is stating about sending an email and for me that is not required. I am relying on you now to get me out from here. Many h hanks in advance. Kindly help